# Invalid JSON primitive when sending POST request of stringify objects

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have ajax function where i am sending two stringify objects like this:

```
function SaveOffsetOrder() {

       var temp = sessionStorage.getItem('book');
       var viewName = $.parseJSON(temp);
       var BookObj = JSON.stringify({ obj: viewName })

       var OffsetCommonModel = {
                ProductId: $('#OffProductId').val(),
                CustomerId: $("#OffCustomerId").val(),

            }

       var OffsetCommonObj = JSON.stringify({ 'OffsetCommonObj': 
                                  OffsetCommonModel });

       $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "Post",             
                url: "@Url.Content("~/Estimate/CreateOffset")",
                data: OffsetCommonObj + '&' + $.param(BookObj),
                dataType: 'json',

               success: function (data) {
               } 
    });
```

this is my action method :-

```
public ActionResult CreateOffset(OffsetCommonModel OffsetCommonObj, CalculationModel obj)
        {
          // do something with objects
        }
```

but when i check in the console its giving error "Invalid JSON primitive"
where i am doing wrong please help..Thanks

Comment: You cannot combine serialized data and stringified data. If you specify `contentType: 'application/json'` then it need to be `data: JSON.stringify({obj: viewName, 'OffsetCommonObj': OffsetCommonModel }),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  but both objects already stringify...why i have to do again?

Comment: Read my comment carefully - you do not stringify each object individually

Comment: And the correct way to generate you url is `url: '@Url.Action("CreateOffset", "Estimate")',`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks Sir..

Comment: **data: OffsetCommonObj + '&' + $.param(BookObj)** in your ajax-call configuration object produces invalid JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Your data part in ajax should be something like this and no need to stringify objects individually, do that once

```
 function SaveOffsetOrder() {

    var temp = sessionStorage.getItem('book');
    var viewName = $.parseJSON(temp);
    //  var BookObj = { obj: viewName }

    var OffsetCommonModel = {
        ProductId: $('#OffProductId').val(),
        CustomerId: $("#OffCustomerId").val(),

    }

    // var OffsetCommonObj = { 'OffsetCommonObj': OffsetCommonModel };

    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "Post",
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Estimate/CreateOffset")",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'OffsetCommonObj': OffsetCommonModel, 'obj': viewName }),
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanku so much @Arun Sir..you saved my day

Comment: happy to help :) If it solve your problem you can mark as answer or vote up

Comment: one more question sir,instead of getting data into OffsetCommonModel  ..what i have to do for serialize the form data. like this -$("#form").serialize()

Comment: You have an array so better to use `$("#form").serializeArray()`

Comment: its means data should be something like this ?  data: JSON.stringify({ 'OffsetCommonObj': $("#OffsetBookForm").serializeArray(), 'obj': viewName }),

Comment: yes, just replace your first object with `$("#OffsetBookForm").serializeArray()`

Comment: In action method now i have passed the viewModel object,but its getting null object in Action Method

Comment: have you tried with `$("#OffsetBookForm").serialize()`